# Font Implementation

Tags: html, css, fonts, stylesheet, custom-font

Here is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'bariol Regular'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('Bariol.ttf'); /*URL to font*/
  }
  </style>
  <body>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

I downloaded a font file called **Bariol.ttf** and placed it in the same folder as this HTML file.

I checked in firebug, the font **'bariol regular'** is not getting applied.

Why?

Comment: you defined a font-face, but you didn't apply to the paragraph.

Comment: @fcalderan: Actually this page is kind of a small Proof of Concept. I want to implement this font across the whole website. on all the pages. Please correct the mistake I'm making and give me the code which would also be workable if I use it for applying the font across the entire website.

Comment: `p { font-family: 'bariol Regular' }`

Comment: @fcalderan: I want it to be applied across the entire website not only to <p> element. I need code for that thing.

Comment: `body { font-family: 'bariol Regular' }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the html and css format you have to make

**HTML**

```
<p>
This is bariol font
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bariol_regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/bariol_regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/bariol_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/bariol_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/bariol_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/bariol_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body{
  font-family: 'bariol_regularregular';
}
```

I have uploaded files on dropbox here are the links just download them and place it in fonts folder next to css folder

bariol_regular-webfont.eot:https://www.dropbox.com/s/wechtcmqoqwirti/bariol_regular-webfont.eot?dl=0

bariol_regular-webfont.ttf:https://www.dropbox.com/s/ms2upt51n9uuond/bariol_regular-webfont.ttf?dl=0

bariol_regular-webfont.woff:https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfeuybbqzisl94m/bariol_regular-webfont.woff?dl=0

bariol_regular-webfont.woff2:https://www.dropbox.com/s/ez55wodao53xhqe/bariol_regular-webfont.woff2?dl=0

> All the required files are uploaded you need to download them and place it in fonts folder next to css folder and call the above css in your css file

Comment: I even downloaded Bariol_Regular.otf file and tried to change the font but still it didn't apply. Why?

Comment: not only the otf and not only the ttf file will work you need to generate complete font face then you will get a kit and apply it on your html page

Comment: Can you give me a complete working example for the same or a small proof of concept like of thing? It would be really helpful to me. Could you please do me a favor?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Accepted and upvoted it too. Just small query. I tried your code for <p> tag in my HTML file it worked. Actually I want to apply this font to all the HTML elements present on all web pages of my entire website. For that what changes I need to be done in above code? Better if you could update code in your answer accordingly. Thanks once again bro.

Answer (score 0):

its because there is no The **Web Open Font Format (WOFF)** file